# Append multiple CSV files with different order of headers

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a directory that contains CSV files that have the same columns but not in the same order. I would like to append them in one CSV file but when do that with **pyspark** using the following code I get the csv but with mixed data inside (i.e. it it is not sorting out the order of the columns correctly).

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

from pyspark.sql.functions import col


sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load('/myPATH/TO_THE_CSV_FILES/')
df.coalesce(1).write.option("header", "true").format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save('/myPATH/TO_APPENDED_CSV_FILE/')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a little trick.

```
cols = a.columns

a = a.select(cols)
b = b.select(cols)

c = a.union(b)
```

Comment: Was Frank's answer, I just edited it. If you're going to do `df.coalesce(1)`, you might as well not use spark. With python/pandas, you could list all files in the directory (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory), use pandas to create a df for each file, and concatenate all the dfs (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435176/appending-two-dataframes-with-same-columns-different-order)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my description but the files are stored in HDFS and cannot be accessed directly using pandas, can I ?