# Unable to sort table / Warning message

Tags: pandas

The output table of the code below isn't sorted although I included the sorting in the code. 
Please see the warning message

I have the same code running for a different dataset and works fine. 
Basically I want to see all the columns that have missing values sorted by ascending values; so I can easily see the columns that have more missing values at the top.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

location = "DC_Properties.csv"
dc_df = pd.read_csv(location)
dc_df.head(7) #print 7 first rows

total = dc_df.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
percent_1 = dc_df.isnull().sum()/dc_df.isnull().count()*100
percent_2 = (round(percent_1, 1)).sort_values(ascending=False)
missing_data = pd.concat([total, percent_2], axis=1, keys=['Total', '%'])
missing_data.head(20)`
```

> `C:\Users\nikil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:5: FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version of pandas will change to not sort by default.
>   To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'.
>   To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass 'sort=True'.`

Comment: Just do what the warning says, pass `sort=False` or `sort=True` to `concat`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas User Warning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501787/python-pandas-user-warning-sorting-because-non-concatenation-axis-is-not-aligne)