# pandas concat reordered columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

It might be duplicate but can`t find the proper question. If so, please, point the link towards it.

pandas 0.25

I have 2 dataframe (`df1` and `df2`), both from `pd.read_csv()` function, everything by default. The first row is a header, there are Cyrillic and English column names. The `df1` has a proper order of columns, `df2` is not. Like:

`df1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'д']`

`df2 = ['b', 'c', 'a', 'д']`

In the case of `concat([df1, df2], axis=0)`, which order of columns will be? It will inherit the order of `df1` or `df2`? Is there any cases (e.g. name of columns), when behavior of the function may change?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but maybe answer should be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501787/python-pandas-user-warning-sorting-because-non-concatenation-axis-is-not-aligne/50501889#50501889)

Comment: @jezrael please, post as answer, I found what I have been looking for by your link, I would like to accept it as an answer.

Comment: It should be dupe, so cannot do it :( Be free upvote linked answer